# on click get the value from array

Tags: javascript

I want to get the value from array on click event. How can i achieve this. Tried some code did not work.

```
var array = ['jane', 'alax', 'russell', 'max'];
var newArr = [];
function myFunction() {
  for(var i=0; i<=array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array);
       newArr.push(array[i]);
   }
}
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = newArr;
```

It should add first jane on first click then second click add alax and so on.

Comment: `var i=0; i<=array.length; ...` this setup won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current scenario, it's iterating over all elements on each click. To make it like one by one use a counter variable which increments on each click until it reaches array length, use it for getting the element to push and finally updates the HTML within the event handler to update on each click.

```js
var array = ['jane', 'alax', 'russell', 'max'];
var newArr = [];
// variable for keep track of clicks
var c = 0;

function myFunction() {
  // check value of counter
  if (c < array.length) {
    // push value and increment counter
    newArr.push(array[c++])
    // set html
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = newArr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically what the script below does is every time you run the function "onCLick", it adds the next item in the list.

```
var i = 0
var array = ['jane', 'alax', 'russell', 'max'];
var newArr = [];
//Init Vars^^

function onClick(){
    console.log(array[i])
    newArr.push(array[i])
    if(i<newArr.length){
        ++i
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by setting an `initialValue` of `0` to point to the first element of the array, then on each successive invocation we increment the `initialValue`  by 1 to fetch the next element into the new array `display` until we exhaust the array.

After adding the element in the `display` array, we simply use `Array.join` to join all the values of the array into a comma separated string.

```js
let clickHandler = (function(){
 const array = ['jane', 'alax', 'russell', 'max'];
 let initialValue = 0;
 let display = [];
 function clickHandler(){
    display = initialValue < array.length ? display.concat(array[initialValue++]): display;
    document.getElementById("res").textContent = display.join();
 }
 return clickHandler;
})();
```

```html
<button onclick="clickHandler()">Click here!</button>
<span id="res"></span>
```